# Errors in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, permissions, vps

I am getting these errors on phpMyAdmin.
I didn't do anything recently and I don't know why this is happening!

```
Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_write_close(): write failed: No space left on device (28)

session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/www/tmp)
```

Here are the df function results:

```
devtmpfs         1929696        0   1929696   0% /dev
tmpfs            1940024       24   1940000   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1940024    25172   1914852   2% /run
tmpfs            1940024        0   1940024   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       39187808 37181080         0 100% /
tmpfs             388008        0    388008   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: yeah! i think thats true!

Comment: is there a way to detect which folder is using too much space?

Comment: Hard to tell, as "using to much space" is arbitrary. But if it worked before, you did nothing and now it does not work, then it is most probably about logs. Look at this: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-the-largest-filesdirectories-on-a-linuxunixbsd-filesystem/